# Check if two nodes are connected

Tags: haskell, recursion, graph

Let `g` be an undirected graph, which for simplicity we will represent as a list of pairs of `Integers`.
For example

```
g = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)]
```

Suppose I already have defined a function `adj node` which gives the ordered list of adjacent nodes to `node` in `g`.
For example

```
> adj 1
[2,3]
> adj 4
[]
```

I would like to check if two nodes are connected looking recursively at adjacent nodes, generalizing to an arbitrary number of checks this function

```
connected start end
| start == end = True
| elem end (adj start) = True
| elem end (extract (map adj (adj start))) = True
| elem end (extract (map adj (extract (map adj (adj start))))) = True
  -- to make this function work on a graph or arbitrary size, I should put here
  -- an endless number of lines like the ones above
| otherwise = False
where
    extract (x:xs) = x ++ extract xs
    extract _ = []
```

Comment: @chaosmasttter `extract` is actually `concat`.

Comment: If you need to check connectedness for many node pairs, an efficient solution could be created using the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall_algorithm) for the transitive closure. In general, have a look at the [Shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

Answer (score 1):

To check recursively you'd have to perform a recursive call. Here it would just be about applying connected to all the members of `adj start` and see if any of the results is true:

```
connected :: Int -> Int -> Bool
connected start end | elem end adjs = True
                    | otherwise     = any (flip connected end) $ adjs
  where  adjs = adj start
```

You'd also have to check for cycles though. That can be done by keeping a list of already encountered nodes, as a first approach. If you care about performance and big graphs then you'd maybe have to use something else than basic lists:

```
connected :: Int -> Int -> Bool
connected start end = go start end [start]
  where
    go start end seen | elem end adjs = True
                      | otherwise     = any (\x -> go x end (x:seen))
                                        . filter (not . (flip elem seen))
                                        $ adjs
      where adjs = adj start
```

Comment: The use of `$` before `adjs` is unnecessary, you would only need it if  you wanted to replace `adjs` directly by `adj` start.

Comment: it is in the second version and I more or less copied it, but yeah, it's optional in the first one